# Biasing a low AC voltage for input to an ADS1115 ADC

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, dc, bias, negative-voltage

I have an AC signal from a position sensor that changes between -200 mV and 200 mV, something like 400mV peak-to-peak.

I have ordered an [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1115) breadboard and I use an STM32 microcontroller.

I'm not sure from the ADS1115 datasheet that I need to bias the signal or if it can accept a negative voltage.

If it does not accept negative voltages, should I bias the signal with a voltage divider and some series capacitor?
How can I bias only 200-250 mV?

Spec of position sensor:

[image]

Comment: What's the source impedance of your position sensor?

Comment: @jonk I cant find it in datasheet, this it what I found :Transimpedance Gain 100 kV/A
(PDP90A 2D Lateral Effect Position Sensor)

Comment: That statement suggests to me that there's an opamp used as a transimpedance amplifier stage and that they are probably using a 100 k Ohm resistor in the feedback path to convert sensor current into sensor voltage. Which suggests that the sensor current is \$\pm2\:\mu\text{A}\$. That also suggests further that the output cannot drive more than about, say, \$5\:\text{mA}\$ to be safer. (Many can do 2, 3, or 4 times that much. But better to be safer than sorry.) Do you see any spec about its output compliance current?

Comment: @jonk ok, so what can I do with this info? Does it mean I can't use a simple voltage divider? maybe I don't need voltage divider bias?

Comment: It probably means you need to use more opamps. Just to be safe. Your ADC supports differential mode. I'd take advantage of that, in this case.

Comment: Photocurrent (Max) : 40 µA

Comment: Well, if they are using a gain of 100 k then that means the output swing, worst case, is \$\pm 4\:\text{V}\$. Hmm. I nailed it! And we needed to see that table! Yeah, the power requirements pretty much tell me that you don't want to draw a lot of current from the output. You will want opamps.

Comment: @jonk because the scanning is short after couple of measures from optical team in my work they said the max negative will be -250 mV and positive will be 250mV

Comment: They'd know. So that's the deal then. Do you want to design for the full output range of this device and ignore what they said to you? Or do you want to take some risks (assume that the output will stay within what they are telling you?)

Comment: Thanks for adding the table for the sensor module and the information from your optics folks. So we have the table, now, and we have statements from your optics folks. This leaves it up to you what you want to design for. You can target the entire range of the sensor module, just on the off chance that your work might be used for different circumstances at a later date using that same sensor module but with different optical inputs. Or you can custom design things for what you are being told to do by them and know that it cannot be used for other situations, should they come up.

Comment: The benefit of the custom design is that you can add some gain to the situation and use more of your ADC range. This may be important to you. (Long discussion, no time for it now.) Limiting yourself to a tiny range means you are only using a very small part of the ADC and this means you've lost a lot of bits of resolution. Almost 4 bits of it. So you are down to like 11 bits if all you do is shift the signal up.

Comment: @jonk sorry jonk I dont know what to do, the board had ordered, maybe I did mistake but now I dont know what to do, some help with this situation voltage (between -250mV to 250mV) , why do I need op amp if the input impedance of ADC is couple of MegaOhm?

Comment: Because you need a way to shift it up (add a voltage) so that it is in range. The sensor output is very likely an opamp with very limited output current compliance. You could call the seller and find out. But without solid information otherwise, I'd assume very limited current compliance. You can also test it, I suppose. Apply a light source and read the output with a meter. Then load it down and read again. And load it more and read once more. From a few documented readings you can determine your own answer. In fact, this is good practice -- keeping a log book for such questions.

Comment: @jonk how can I shift it up ? with voltage divider like the answer of PStechPaul?

Comment: You could certainly try that. But if you do load the source down with 2k, like that, make sure you do some experiments first with a 2k resistor to make sure it doesn't change the measured output with a good quality meter also applied in parallel with the sample load. If it doesn't shift at all, then I think you may be fine. Use a switch with the 2k. Toggle it back and forth while watching the meter results. (Keep in mind that even in the case where 2k is a fine load, you are still losing almost 5 bits of precision with the divider added.)

Comment: could you tell me please how im losing 5 bits? how you calculate it ?

Comment: Your ADC is 16 bit, but one bit is basically noise (as I've cursorily read, anyway.) But that's over its entire range, which I take is 5 V. (Tell me if that's wrong, as I've not seen a spec for your breadboard.) The divider will cut the signal in half, too. So you are looking at about \$\pm 100\:\text{mV}\$. Or a span of \$200\:\text{mV}\$. If you take the base-2 logarithm of 5 V divided by 0.2 V, you'll see that it is close to 5. And that comes off of the top of the 15 good bits you have. So 10 left over. Oh, well. If you apply some gain, though? Then much better.

Comment: what about the input impedance of ADC ? its sufficient, for single-ended input?

Comment: Sure, it's fine for single-ended. Has a mode for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16-bit w/PGA ADC ADS1115 is not ideal here because the internal reference voltage is inaccessible.

Input voltage must be kept in the range between the power supply rails at all times. You could do something like this using differential inputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmXY4d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Differential voltage is nominally zero with 0V from the sensor and is +/-1.024V for +/-4V from the sensor. You can set the PGA to get an appropriate gain for your signal.

Comment: however if the voltage that the sensor output is between -300mV to 300mV? the position doesn't change so much (something like 3mm that translate to +/- 300mV)

Comment: At the highest PGA gain F.S. Is +/-256mV which represents about +/-1V at the sensor. So you get less than full resolution with this simple circuit. But still quite a bit of resolution- 32uV LSB approximately.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a voltage divider from the sensor output to Vdd, and it will shift the signal to 1/2 Vdd, although half the amplitude.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWudcK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the sensor has dual power supplies.
NB: I have seen some ADS1115 boards with 2.5V reference onboard.
Sorry, mistaken. It is [AD7705](https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/265219027881?hash=item3dc04933a9:g:hxkAAOSw-Opg4nRv&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoGNyiQYCF10Kqv6nTPwYmos%2F2IqBt04YOTgAfhr3UDVFbU%2BRpXhFpXpvnNQLhdou3xc4GPVxYex7p6F%2BR8HMoYKw45X0VbuJKsojex4VuwtMalKj%2FPEhTJnMVtSfzst2GmG8dDeFjoKeZ7vZMOnJL4nfalJ9B5kuCPGWWX803f1r27AZ6ysIjEgEnTzHTMY7SqSVLHmii%2FF2zMn0IJfhaxE%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8CQr4TxYA), AD7705 16-bit ADC Data Acquisition.

Let's use a voltage "translator" with some gain.
"High" precision Opamp needed. Lowest offset versus temperature ([chopped](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2652.pdf?ts=1664367174228&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLC2652) ?).
Note that the resistors are at least 0.01% tolerance and calibration/offset should be used (low value serial potentiometers needed?).
Note also that one can swap reference and voltage inputs (with some adjustments).

[image]